# extracting data from nested dictionary by python

Tags: dictionary

I am trying to extract data from a JSON file, and am still not clear about the error coming. My data is like this:

**"Tracker":{"Sep 30, 2021":{"DC":4,"DN":"0:0",**

```
DC = {}

for day, daily_data in read_content['Tracker'].items():


for  value in daily_data['Disturbances Count']:
  
    DC[datetime] = value
```

Im getting the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

The solution for the above code only to add str

```
DC = {}
```

for day, daily_data in read_content['Tracker'].items():

for  value in str(daily_data['Disturbances Count']):

```
DC[datetime] = value
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).